# excel download methods are not getting called .net core c#

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, asp.net-core-3.1

GetHistoricalData(), GetAnalyticsDetail(), GetInfraAnalyticsDetail() methods are getting executed and returning the datatables dt1, dt2, dt3 but the exceldownload methods are not hitting, logs are also captured until the 'Excel Extract method call started' but the other logs are not getting logged. Any issue with the code which is written ? Find the code snippet below.

```
    public void GetDataForExcel()
    {
        try { 
        SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.LogMessages("Repository - ", "Excel Extract method call started");
        string folderPath = _configuration["AnalyticsData:DirectoryPath"];
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            //If Directory (Folder) does not exists. Create it.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }

        GetHistoricalData();
        GetAnalyticsDetail();
        GetInfraAnalyticsDetail();
        SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.LogMessages("Repository - ", "Starting the save function");
        excelDownload(dt1, "DummySheet1", null, null);
        excelDownload(dt2, "DummySheet2", "DummySheet3", dt3);
    }
       catch(Exception ex)
        {
            SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.Log("Repository -  ", "Excel Extract method call exception", ex);
            throw (ex);
        }

    }
```

```
public void excelDownload(DataTable dt, String sheetName, string? sheetName1, DataTable? dTable)
        {
            SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.LogMessages("Repository - ", "Excel Download method call outside try");
            try
            {
                SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.LogMessages("Repository - " , "Excel Download method call started");
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCellrange;

                //  get Application object.
                excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                excel.Visible = false;
                excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

                // Creation a new Workbook
                excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);


                // Workk sheet
                excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
                excelSheet.Name = sheetName;

                // loop through each row and add values to our sheet
                var rowcount = 1;

                foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    rowcount += 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // on the first iteration we add the column headers
                        if (rowcount == 3)
                        {
                            excelSheet.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                        }
                        // Filling the excel file 
                        excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();
                    }
                }

                if (sheetName1 != null)
                {
                    excelworkBook.Sheets.Add();
                    excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;

                    excelSheet.Name = sheetName1;
                    rowcount = 1;

                    foreach (DataRow datarow in dTable.Rows)
                    {
                        rowcount += 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= dTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            // on the first iteration we add the column headers
                            if (rowcount == 3)
                            {
                                excelSheet.Cells[1, i] = dTable.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                            }
                            // Filling the excel file 
                            excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                string folderPath = _configuration["AnalyticsData:DirectoryPath"];
                string savePath = folderPath.Replace("/", "\\");
                excelworkBook.SaveAs(@savePath + sheetName + ".xlsx");
                SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.LogMessages("Repository - ", sheetName + " Saved");
                excelworkBook.Close();
                excel.Quit();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SharedLibrary.LogManager.Logger.Log("Repository -  Excel Save", "Error", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use Excel Interop in a web application. It requires a new Excel license for *every single user*, it doesn't scale, it leaves ghost Excel instances still running if an error occurs. Which is almost certainly the case here. The Excel format (xlsx) is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files. You can easily create Excel files without Excel using libraries like EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML, SpreadTheLight. With EPPlus, all this code can be replaced with a single `ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt);`

Comment: Thanks..i have used closexml and it worked